# Using `callgrind` to count function calls in Linux

Tags: performance, valgrind, perf, callgrind

I am trying to track function call counts on a program I'm interested in. If I run the program on its own, it will run fine. If I try to run it with valgrind using the command seen below I seem to be getting a different result.

Command run:
[image]

Produces this input immediately, even though the execution is normally slow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

valgrind has [limited floating point support](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=414870). You're probably using non-standard or very large floats.

UPDATE: since you're using `long double`, you're outta luck. Unfortunately,

> Your least-worst option
> is to find a way to make your world work just using standard IEEE754
> 64-bit double precision.

This probably isn't easy considering you're using an existing project.

Comment: It's unlikely to be related to x87 instructions.

Comment: @PaulFloyd: The stack trace includes `long_double_max()`.  If that's using the C++ `long double` type, that's the 80-bit x87 type even on x86-64, on non-Windows systems.  OTOH it's `cpp_dec_float`, so decimal float?  IDK, might not be using hardware FP at all.    Running under GDB might allow examining the instruction that triggered the exception, or I guess we have the absolute addresses from the backtrace so the OP could disassemble that function.

Comment: The project is indeed using `long double`'s

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this is more likely to be related to [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442168) issue. However to be certain you will need to tell us

1. what compilation options are being used - specifically are you using anything related to AVX or x87?
2. What hardware this is running on.

It would help if you can cut this down to a small example and either update this or the frexp bugzilla items.

Comment: I'm trying to test this application [https://github.com/gyoto/Gyoto/tree/da5b07150bcdfe0626eb1ed1a2edf5fd5ce13096] and I believe it is using both `long double` types and avx instructions. I am running it on a Linux based VM, that can otherwise run the program on its own.

Comment: It's going to be difficult to find the time/motivation to build that.

Comment: I feel you on that